# php preg_match pattern problem,regular expression pattern

Tags: php, regex

```
<tr  id='ieconn3' >
  <td><table width='100%'><tr><td valign='top'><table width='100%'><tr><td>aaaaa
<br>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>
```

I want to get the `aaaaa` part till `<br>` or `</td>`. I tried lots of patterns but didnt work. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t try to use regular expressions to parse HTML as HTML is not a regular language and thus cannot be described with regular expressions. Use a proper HTML parser instead.

If you’re using XHTML, you can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to parse it as XML and query it with [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath). And for HTML documents, you can use the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). And [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) can even handle both XHTML and HTML.

Comment: I am not gonns parse html I am just getting content in tags

Comment: @kk: But you need to parse the HTML code to get the proper contents.

Comment: <tr  id='ieconn2' >
  <td><table width='100%'><tr><td valign='top'><table width='100%'><tr><td>THIS PART ONLY<br>

I want to get THIS PART ONLY but it gives me 1 child node. and with out any html tags I cant preg_replace?

Answer (score 0):

As Gumbo pointed out, this will only result in a giant mess if you insist on using a regexp for this. However, if you are sure the HTML does not chance, this one will do the trick:

`/<tr><td>(.*)<\/td><\/tr>/`

use like this:

```
$string = "<tr  id='ieconn3' >
<td><table width='100%'><tr><td valign='top'><table width='100%'><tr><td>aaaaa<br>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>";

$matches = array();
preg_match("/<tr><td>(.*)<\\/td><\\/tr>/", $string, $matches);

print($matches[1]);
```